# Confusion regarding injectiveness of operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory

I am doing an assignment regarding the operator $T:L^2(-1,3)\rightarrow L^2(-1,3),\ Tx(t)=tx(t).$ More specifically, I am considering the operator $T-\lambda I$. I am supposed to show that for $\lambda\in [-1,3]$ that $T-\lambda I$ is invertible in the sense that it is injective (the definition on invertibility from the book we use), but I am having issues with that.

$\textbf{What I have done:}$ The operator $T-\lambda I$ is linear so it suffices to show that if $(T-\lambda I)x(t)=0\Rightarrow x(t)=0$. But since $(T-\lambda I)x(t)=x(t)(t-\lambda)=0$ this can only be the case if $\lambda\not\in [-1,3]$ since if both $t\in [-1,3]$ and $\lambda\in [-1,3]$ then it is possible for $t-\lambda=0$ hence $x(t)$ does not necessarily need to be $0$ thus I can not manage to show that the operator is injective.

Am I doing something wrong or is it perhaps a mistake that $\lambda\in [-1,3]$? Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the definition of invertibility for operators in some $L^2$ space is unique: they are invertibles if they are injective AND surjective. Thus, you want to prove that $T-\lambda I$ is invertible or just injective? For the second you need to show that $\lambda $ is not an eigenvalue of $T$

Comment: for injectivity you have that $x(t)(t-\lambda )=0$ if and only if $x=0$ a.e. because the functions defined by $t-\lambda $ can never be zero a.e. Thus $T-\lambda I$ is injective for any chosen $\lambda $

Comment: I am asked to prove that it is invertible but it only states that I have to show it is injective. In the assignment I previously proved directly that for $\lambda\not\in [-1,3]$ that $T-\lambda I$ is invertible (left and right inverse exists) and that it is bounded and exists on $L^2(-1,3)$.

Comment: But what if $t=\lambda$? That is possible since they are in the same interval? Then it does not necessarily hold.

Comment: you need to prove that $t-\lambda \neq 0$ a.e., it doesn't care if $t-\lambda =0$ when $t=\lambda $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that $L^2([-1,3])$ is a **function space** and $T:L^2([-1,3])\to L^2([-1,3])$, therefore we says that $(T-\lambda I)f=0$ if the LHS of the previous equality is the **zero function**.

Then you need to prove that $(T-\lambda I)f=0$ if and only if $f$ is the zero function. Then you have that
$$
(T-\lambda I)f=0\iff g(t):=f(t)(t-\lambda )=0 \text{ almost everywhere }\tag1
$$
for some chosen $f\in L^2([-1,3])$. Now note that the function defined by $h(t):=t-\lambda $ cannot be the zero function for any chosen constant $\lambda \in \Bbb C $ because the set $\{t\in [-1,3]:t\neq \lambda \}$ have full measure, that is, $\lambda (\{t\in [-1,3]:t\neq \lambda \})=4$.
Hence $\rm(1)$ holds only if $f$ is the zero function (shortly written as $f=0$).

Comment: Thank you for elaborating on that! It makes more sense now. I haven't had any measure theory before (neither in the course I'm doing the assignment for) so I'm not very familiar with the notion of being zero almost everywhere.

Comment: @James indeed in the $L^p$ spaces we don't say "almost everywhere" because it is a quotient space, I added it to clarify the prose. That is: each "function" in an $L^p$ space is in reality an equivalence class of functions who differs only in sets of measure zero.